# combine Observable and Promise

Tags: rx-java, rxjs, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a service, `MyService`, which has a method `getList()` which returns an Observable of an array of Items, something like

```
getList(): Observable<Item[]>
```

Once the list is retrieved, then each Item needs to go through a second method of `MyService`, `fillItem(Item)`. This method issues a request to some back end which returns a Promise, something like:

```
fillItem(item: Item) {
   BackEnd.retrieveDetails(item.id)
          .then(data => item.data = data);
}
```

What I need is to combine the above two methods so that MyService is able to return an Observable which emits the list of Items once all of them have been filled with their data (i.e. once all Promises have been resolved).

What I have tried so far is something along these lines

```
fillAll(items: Item[]) {
   const promises = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      const item = items[i];
      promises.push(this.fillItem(item));
   }
   const subject = new Subject<Item[]>();
   Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
                subject.next(items);
            },
            err => {
                subject.error(err);
            });
   return subject.asObservable();
}

getListWithFilledItems() {
   return this.getList()
              .map(items => this.fillAll(items))
}
```

Unfortunately, if I do so, the method `getListWithFilledItems()` returns an `Observable<Observable<Item[]>>` and not, as I hoped, an `Observable<Item[]>`.

Any suggestion on how to change the code so that the method `getListWithFilledItems()` returns an `Observable<Item[]>` would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of `.map(items => this.fillAll(items))` you can use just `mergeMap()`:

```
.mergeMap(items => this.fillAll(items))
```

This will subscribe to the Observable returned from `fillAll()` and reemit its value when it's ready.

Btw, be aware that you're not calling `complete()` on the internal `subject` so the Observable chain isn't disposed properly (however it might not event matter in your use-case).

Comment: I forgot to thank for the quick response that actually has made my code work. I am still struggling a bit to understand why mergeMap works while switchMap doesn't, but I recognize that Rx and Observables are the most intellectually challenging and stimulating thing I have come across (professionally) since many many years.